# When should I override basic_streambuf::seekoff?

Tags: c++, stl, stream

I am writing a custom binary stream buffer inheriting from the standard `std::streambuf` interface. This stream buffer needs to support writing and reading to an external block of memory (not owned by the stream). So far, I could get away with only overriding the `underflow` and `overflow` member functions, which call `setp`, `pbump`, and `setg` with the right positions, handle the logic to circumvent the [limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/388) of Microsoft's STL only accepting `int` values for offsets (which causes problems with large objects), and get/set a byte using `pptr` and `gptr`.

This has worked well for a while. Recently, when attempting to use this class in another context, the input stream using my stream buffer went into fail state almost immediately. I realized that the default implementation of `std::streambuf::seekoff` is to do nothing and return `-1`, which is why the fail bit was set. I guess previous usage of the stream buffer never ended up calling `seekoff`, and this went unnoticed.

Doing some research on other people's experience in implementing custom stream buffers, I rarely see `seekoff` (and it's companion `seekpos`) being overriden. [Boost ASIO's basic_streambuf](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/basic_streambuf.hpp) does not. [This article on writing custom stream buffers](http://videocortex.io/2017/custom-stream-buffers/) and [this other article](https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/deriving-from-stdstreambuf/) (both show up on the first page in a Google search) do not.

I did see the various STL implementations of `basic_stringbuf` use it, though ([MSVC](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/sstream), [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/sstream.tcc), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/sstream)).

Is it an error not to implement `seekoff` and `seekpos`? Based on what I understand of streams, the implementation in `basic_stringbuf` effectively forwards the call to `setg` and `setp` with the proper read/write pointers, and this implementation should be applicable to all streams. If so, why is this not the default behavior? I understand it may not be optimal, but the standard does provide working and non-optimal default implementations for `xsgetn` and `xsputn`. What I am missing?